# How do I make google api request with firebase authentication?

Tags: firebase, oauth-2.0, google-photos, google-photos-api

I'm trying to fetch google api data within my firebase app.
After login using `firebase.auth().signInWithPopup`, i get `accessToken` and `idToken`.

What I'm trying to do is after sign in, redirect to another page and fetch album data from google photos api with accessToken.

Here is my code for **sign-in**

```js
export const signInWithGoogle = async () => {
  try {
    const response: any = await auth.signInWithPopup(provider);
    const { accessToken, idToken } = response.credential;
    localStorage.setItem('accessToken', accessToken);
    localStorage.setItem('idToken', idToken);
  } catch(e) {
    console.log(e)
  }
}
```

and this is what I'm gonna do in redirected page

```js
const onClick = async (e) => {
  const accessToken = localStorage.getItem('accessToken');
  const response = await fetch('https://photoslibrary.googleapis.com/v1/albums', {
    headers: {
      Authorization: `Bearer ${accessToken}`,
    },
  })
  console.log(await response.json());
}
```

I actually get right data with above code but is it a good idea to store access token to local storage?
If it's not safe, how do I get access token in redirected page? or what is suggested/best practice for requesting google api in client side?